# I can't save appscript.json after manual change

Tags: javascript, google-developers-console

I researched here on the blog and found that "appscript.json", does not allow saving if there is a syntax error.

I am not finding error, if someone can help me please.

```
 {
   "oauthScopes":[ 
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
   ],
   "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
   "dependencies": {
   },
   "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
   "runtimeVersion": "V8"
 }
```

I'm new to scripting, I've tried making several changes, but I couldn't find the syntax error that's preventing me from saving the project.

Comment: The JSON looks fine to me. Are you sure you can't save because of a syntax error?

Comment: Maybe the issue lies with your editor or the file. You may want to check that you have the correct permissions to access the sheet and that the sheet exists in your google sheets account

Comment: Searching here on the blog, I found that one of the reasons for not being able to save is due to a syntax error.
But I didn't check other problems related to the worksheet...
The spreadsheet is my creation, but I'll check.

Comment: My .json file doesn't save after I add the "oauthScopes" line.
That's why I commented that it could be a syntax error.